# I can't type the ref correctly using useRef hook in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I'm trying to pass a ref from a parent component (an EditableCell) to a Child component (Input) and use its `.current.focus` property when the parent is clicked.

I'm using the `forwardRef` function using typescript but I have trouble typing it correctly

```js
interface Props {
  // Some props type
}

const CellEditable = (props: Props) => {
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  const handleClick = () => setEditing(!isEditing)

  const opts = {
    ref: inputRef,
    value: props.value,
    onChange: props.onChange
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {
        isEditing
        ? <InputText {...opts} />
        : <div>{props.value}</div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
interface Props {
  // Some props type
}

type Ref = HTMLInputElement

const InputText = forwardRef((props: Props, ref: Ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref?.current?.focus()
  })
  
  return (
    <input
      type='text'
      ref={ref}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
    />
  )
})
```

With the code above, I get the following error:

```sh
Argument of type '(props: Props, ref: Ref) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<unknown, Props>'.
  Types of parameters 'ref' and 'ref' are incompatible.
    Type '((instance: unknown) => void) | MutableRefObject<unknown> | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.  TS2345
```

If I type the `forwardRed` with generics, I get a different kind of error:

```js
const InputText = forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => { ... }
```

```sh
Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.
  Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.  TS2339
```

Finally, typing the ref as `any` give me no error.

I am new to Typescript and I don't understand the error mentioned above.

Comment: `forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>((props, ref) => {})` - Can you try this?

Comment: I'm getting the second error: `Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.`

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

Check out following sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-night-3pwjs.

TypeScript warns you that your ref could be possibly null, therefore any code with `ref.current` should be wrapped with if statement, which will ensure that `ref.current` exists.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin but I see tow difference between my code and yours. 1) My ref is passed down to the child component and I cannot find the right type for the ref props (passed via forwardRef). with `any` it works but not when I try to type it correctly. 2) Isn't `ref?.current?.focus()` already a null check? However, I tried with a regular if statement and it doesn't work either

Comment: @eakl Yes, there is a difference. For some reason ref is not obligatory attribute for InputText component, despite the fact that we correctly typed the forwardRef. I suppose, this is how forwardRef is working... Check this out: if you do not pass inputRef  to InputText typescript will not complain about anything. Therefore it could be null in InputText. On the other hand, you can call inputRef in parent component, where it was created. All examples in this article https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315 have the same pattern.